# How did the robot recharge her power in "Ex Machina"?

Tags: ex-machina

In the movie *Ex Machina* we meet an AI.

During the movie we discover that "it" has induction plates so it can recharge.

> At the very end of the movie the robot escapes and there is a scene shown of the robot in different clothes. This might indicate that a (some) time has passed. How is the robot still functioning?

Comment: There are induction chargers at Starbucks.

Comment: erm... its not a pocket phone, its a robot. doubt that it would be 3-5 V battery that can keep a machine of that complexity running. And even if she somehow could go to a Starbucks and put her feet on the plates for indetermined abount of time wouldnt that seem strange?

Comment: That was not a serious answer.

Comment: Nope, it was a comment. :)